# How to do a conditional count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which the query is working fine

```
SELECT answers.answer,answers.id,answers.user_id,COUNT(vote.vote)
              FROM user_answers AS answers
              LEFT JOIN user_answer_vote AS vote ON answers.id =vote.answer_id
              WHERE answers.question_id = $question_id
              GROUP BY answers.id ORDER BY  COUNT(vote.vote) DESC
```

The query is returning as expected but the problem is that the vote.vote column is having both -eve and +eve value I want it to count only +eve values how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case..when` statement

`COUNT(case when vote.vote='+eve' then 1 end)`

within the query

```
SELECT a.answer,a.id,a.user_id, 
       COUNT(case when v.vote='+eve' then 1 end)  
    -- SUM(v.vote='+eve') might be another alternative for the above COUNT
  FROM user_answers AS a
  LEFT JOIN user_answer_vote AS v
    ON a.id =v.answer_id
 WHERE a.question_id = $question_id
 GROUP BY a.id 
 ORDER BY COUNT(case when vote.vote='+eve' then 1 end) DESC
       -- SUM(v.vote='+eve') might be another alternative for the above COUNT
```

**Edit** (due to your comment) :

```
SELECT a.answer,a.id,a.user_id, 
       SUM(case when v.vote='+eve' then 1 else -1 end )
  FROM user_answers AS a
  LEFT JOIN user_answer_vote AS v
    ON a.id =v.answer_id
 WHERE a.question_id = $question_id
 GROUP BY a.id 
 ORDER BY SUM(case when v.vote='+eve' then 1 else -1 end ) DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo for aggregations above](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ef1371ed16d60da0d34bc89a689c60e5)</kbd>

Comment: Yeah it is working great is there  any way to reduce negative value from the result and display the result in at that order +eve i am using +1 and -eve i am using -1

Comment: @AdminRoy I think you want the bottom part of my answer in your comment, don't you?

Comment: I actually want in at this way for example if the vote is contains three entries in which two are +eve so the sum will be 2 and one will be -1 so the total vote will be 2-1=1 how can i do that?

Comment: @AdminRoy the second query(in the edit part) does what you want.

Comment: @AdminRoy what results are you expecting as COUNT and SUM can/will work different on values like  1, 0 and NULL or negative values values, consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFCF1pxt2dr2nrFsp4vEzc/3) .. Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)